# Issue with several replacements in a function under certain conditions

Tags: functions, replacement, assumptions, variable-definitions, variable

I am trying to define a function (reduce[x]) which does several substitutions, depending on the values of certain parameters. Concretely, consider an expression x, which contains an arbitrary number of terms of the type `J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}`. Crucially, n1, n2 and n3 will always be numbers, while m1, m2 and m3 will always be variables (for example, m) which are either zero or greather than zero.

If `n1>1` I wish to do a substitution, otherwise the expression stays the same. Not only that, the replacement will be different whenever m1, m2 and m3 are different than zero and whenever one of them is zero. Therefore, consider the following function which takes whatever expression `x` containing different terms of `J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}` and does the following replacements

```
reduce[x_] := 
  x /. J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}] /; 
    m1 != 0 /; m2 != 0 /; m3 != 0 /; n1> 1 /;n2 !=  0 /; n3 != 0 -> n1/m1 /. J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}] /; 
    m1 = 0 /; m2 != 0 /; m3 != 0 /; n1> 1 /;n2 !=  0 /; n3 != 0 -> n2/m2 /. J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}] /; 
    m1 != 0 /; m2 = 0 /; m3 != 0 /; n1> 1 /;n2 !=  0 /; n3 != 0 -> n3/m3 /. J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}] /; 
    m1 != 0 /; m2 != 0 /; m3 = 0 /; n1> 1 /;n2 !=  0 /; n3 != 0 -> n1+n2+n3
```

where I don't show the rest of replacements whenever two of the m's are zero or all three of them are zero, as hopefully it's not needed to understand my problem. My issue is that m1, m2 and m3 are not numbers, insetad they are variables (that are always equal or greater than zero), and therefore when evaluating

```
reduce[J[{m, 2}, {m, 1}, {m, 1}]]
```

The function won't work, as it doesn't know that m is different from zero. I tried defining global assumptions so that m is set to be different than zero, but it doesn't work (even after using Simplify). Therefore I am missing something, I think the issue is that the function expects m1, m2 and m3 to be numbers, and even using assumptions on m1, m2, m3 it doesn't seem to work. Any advice? I have the feeling it should have an easy solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out or find one.

Comment: In `reduce[J[{m, 2}, {m, 1}, {m, 1}]]` since `m` does not have a numeric value it cannot be determined to be non-zero in each of the tests for `m1`, `m2` and `m3`. You would need to eliminate the constraints on `m1`, `m2` and `m3`.  For example, `reduce[x_] := x /. (J[{m1_, n1_?(# > 1 &)}, {m2_, n2_?(# != 0 &)}, {m3_, n3_?(# != 0 &)}] :> n1)` then `reduce[J[{m, 2}, {m, 1}, {m, 1}]]` evaluates to `2`

Comment: I agree with you and that is what I did at first, but my problem is that if one of the m's is zero, then I don't want to do such replacement, I only want it if the m's are different than zero. Otherwise, if any m is zero, another replacement is made, which I am not showing for clarity. So, since the expression x within reduce[x] might contain many J[{m1,n1},{m2,n2},{m3,n3}] with different values of m's, I need to constrain such replacement to only when all m's are different than zero. Is it therefore impossible to do in this manner because m doesn't have a numeric value?

Comment: Try `reduce[x_] := x /. (J[{m1_, n1_?(# > 1 &)}, {m2_, n2_?(# != 0 &)}, {m3_, n3_?(# != 0 &)}] :> ConditionalExpression[n1, Simplify[m1 != 0 && m2 != 0 && m3 != 0]])`. You could also put all of the tests into the condition for the `ConditionalExpression`

Comment: It seems to work, I get the output `ConditionalExpression[2,m1!=0&&m2!=0&&m3!=0]` for reduce[J[{m, 2}, {m, 1}, {m, 1}]]. It's not exactly what I am looking for though, I only want n1 to be the output as I need to further manipulate the expression. If I understand correctly your code returns n1 and explicitly indicates that all m's must be different than zero, but the code is not checking that they are different than zero.

Comment: With `ConditionalExpression` you will get `Undefined` when the test fails. You might instead want to look at using `Piecewise` No test will work if the `m` do not have values or you do not include assumptions to `Simplify`

Comment: Indeed I got `Undefined`when it failed, which is good. But what if I want to do further replacements? Meaning, I do the replacement I showed, but then I also want do `x /. J[{m1_, n1_}, {m2_, n2_}, {m3_, n3_}] /; 
    m1 = 0 /; m2 != 0 /; m3 != 0 /; n1> 1 /;n2 !=  0 /; n3 != 0 -> n2` when m1=0. If I used your code I would get undefinied at first for such terms, and thus I wouldn't be able to consider the case m1=0. As to the assumptions to `Simplify`, could you elaborate on how to do so? I tried but it didn't work, so I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to clarify your question to include what output you expect under various conditions.

Comment: Fair enough, I will edit the question then.